# Build hierarchical list from flat list

Tags: java

I have list which contains all parents and children represented by same type(class). I want to generate hierarchical list from the flat list.

Below is my Class Which represents both parents and children. Here I need to map children for parent based on **parentId**. Root level(No Parents) is start with parentId **0**.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Customers {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int parentId;
    private List<Customers> childs;

    public Customers(int id, String name, int parentId) {
        this(id, name, parentId, null);
    }

    public Customers(int id, String name, int parentId, List<Customers> childs) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.childs = childs;
    }

}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Input List
        Customers customer = new Customers(1, "Hel", 0);
        Customers customerChild1 = new Customers(2, "Hel-Child1", 1);
        Customers customerChild2 = new Customers(5, "Hel-Child2", 1);
        Customers customerInnerChild1 = new Customers(3, "Hel-InnerChild1", 2);
        Customers customerInnerChild2 = new Customers(4, "Hel-InnerChild2", 2);

        List<Customers> customers = new ArrayList();
        customers.add(customerInnerChild1);
        customers.add(customerInnerChild2);
        customers.add(customer);
        customers.add(customerChild1);
        customers.add(customerChild2);
    }

    public static List<Customers> hierarchicalList(List<Customers> Customers) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I will pass `List<Customer>` as an input to some method. That method should return `List<Customer>` with parent and child relationships.

I need help to build parent and child relation in optimized way.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hel",
    "parentId": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Hel-Child2",
    "parentId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Hel-InnerChild2",
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Hel-InnerChild1",
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Hel-Child1",
    "parentId": 1
  }
]
```

Expecting Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hel",
    "parentId": 0,
    "childs": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Hel-Child1",
        "parentId": 1,
        "childs": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Hel-InnerChild1",
            "parentId": 2
          }, {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Hel-InnerChild2",
            "parentId": 2
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Hel-Child2",
        "parentId": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Note**: Input list is not sorted.

Comment: "That method should return List with parent and child relationships." I don't get what you mean. A combined list?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe that would give us a glimpse into what you might mean by "hierarchical list".

Comment: @daniu, updated my question. I didn't try anything.

Comment: @hellzone , Updated my question please check.

Comment: I just don't get how do you know Hel-InnerChild1 and Hel-InnerChild2 are child of Hel-Child1 but not Hel-Child2?

Comment: @hellzone, Those are stored in database based on user preferences.

Comment: @swarooppallapothu I mean How can I know from your input?

Comment: based on parentId attribute

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to check who's the parent of each child, you just need to filter the list and set the child for each element. Something like this:

```
public List<Customer> getHierarchicalList(final List<Customer> originalList) {
    final List<Customer> copyList = new ArrayList<>(originalList);

    copyList.forEach(element -> {
        originalList
                .stream()
                .filter(parent -> parent.id == element.parentId)
                .findAny()
                .ifPresent(parent -> {
                    if (parent.childs == null) {
                        parent.childs = new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    parent.childs.add(element);
                    originalList.remove(element);
                });
    });
    return originalList;
}
```

Comment: It is going to infinite loop, Can you try with my input.

Comment: Well, I didn't got a infinite loop running your input here... But there was a NPE when adding a child to a null childList... I've changed the method to avoid the NPE but I encourage you to initialize the child array inside the constructors, so it will never be NULL.

Comment: Exception i got: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
 at com.collections.Customers.toString(Application.java:58)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
 at com.collections.Customers.toString(Application.java:58)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)

Comment: Alright, now running my code I got the same output you suggested inside your question. But even now I cannot get this infinite loop man. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE... If you want more help with this you can talk to me in private, I'll be happy to help: rhuankarlus@gmail.com

Comment: when i try this code, i only get 2 level recursive ..not getting into 3 above

Answer (score 2):

I want to extend Rhuan answer,

by using Rhuan's code you will get all the node were laying on the root level, and only one which have the correct content and order, by removing the wrong content you will get better results:

```
public List<Customer> getHierarchicalList(final List<Customer> originalList) {
    final List<Customer> copyList = new ArrayList<>(originalList);

    copyList.forEach(element -> {
        originalList
                .stream()
                .filter(parent -> parent.id == element.parentId)
                .findAny()
                .ifPresent(parent -> {
                    if (parent.childs == null) {
                        parent.childs = new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    parent.childs.add(element);
                    /* originalList.remove(element); don't remove the content before completing the recursive */
                });
    });
    originalList.subList(1, originalList.size()).clear();
    return originalList;
}
```

note about the subList clear.

Answer (score 1):

I also want to extend Rhuan answer.

If you have infinite loop as result of his code, you need to compare parent and element id, they shouldn't be equal `parent.id != element.id`.

So your code will be:

```
public List<Customer> getHierarchicalList(final List<Customer> originalList) {
    final List<Customer> copyList = new ArrayList<>(originalList);

    copyList.forEach(element -> {
        originalList
                .stream()
                .filter(parent -> parent.id == element.parentId && parent.id != element.id)
                .findAny()
                .ifPresent(parent -> {
                    if (parent.childs == null) {
                        parent.childs = new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    parent.childs.add(element);
                    originalList.remove(element);
                });
    });
    return originalList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote this `Collector` for this exact purpose:

```java
public static final <K, E, R> Collector<R, ?, List<E>> intoHierarchy(
    Function<? super R, ? extends K> keyMapper,
    Function<? super R, ? extends K> parentKeyMapper,
    BiFunction<? super R, ? super List<E>, ? extends E> recordMapper
) {
    record Tuple3<T1, T2, T3>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3) {}
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, r -> {
            List<E> e = new ArrayList<>();
            return new Tuple3<R, C, E>(r, e, recordMapper.apply(r, e));
        }),
        m -> {
            List<E> r = new ArrayList<>();
 
            m.forEach((k, v) -> {
                K parent = parentKeyMapper.apply(v.t1());
                E child = v.t3();
 
                if (m.containsKey(parent))
                    m.get(parent).t2().add(child);
                else
                    r.add(child);
            });
 
            return r;
        }
    );
}
```

You can now map your hierarchy as follows:

```java
List<Customers> hierarchy = customers
    .stream()
    .collect(intoHierarchy(
        c -> c.id,
        c -> c.parentId,
        (c, l) -> new Customer(c.id, c.name, c.parentId, l)
    ));
```

Other solutions seem to be `O(N^2)`. This is `O(N)`

Answer (score 0):

This class is hierarchical already.

If you print the parent, then print the children recursively, you'll see a tree.

What do you expect to happen?

It's just a question of how you want to iterate over the tree: depth first or breadth first?

Your question about going from a flat list to the tree is about parsing the flat list.  How do you distinguish parents from children in the flat list?  That should give you a hint on how to proceed.

You'll need a factory class that takes a List of Customer, parses the List, and returns the root instance of Customer with its children in the appropriate tree structure.

Comment: Updated my question with actual input expected output. Can you check.

Comment: Should be easy.  Walk the list and examine each entry.  If it has a parent id, add it to the parent list.  There should be only one customer without a parent.  That's the root of the tree.

Comment: Here i have n Parent's in root level and n child levels. So, i am looking for good solution that will be efficient. I may iterate 100,000 items.

Comment: I was taught that a tree had a single root.  If you have multiple roots you have multiple trees, not one.